# In GCP Airflow - tensorflow 2.12.0 requires numpy<1.24,>=1.22, but you'll have numpy 1.24.4 which is incompatible

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I'm trying to install python packages in the airflow pypi console in GCP. While installing a package that requires numpy>=1.24, this gives a conflict with the tensorflow as it requires <1.24 for tensorflow. If I reduce the tf version then that becomes incompatible with my required package (reliability).
I don't understand how to resolve this.

**ERROR:**

> ERROR: After October 2020 you may experience errors when installing or updating packages. This is because pip will change the way that it resolves dependency conflicts.

Any help on how to fix this please?

Thanks in advance!